# Adding showinfo=0 to youtube iframe doesn't always work

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using the following code to add the Youtube video to the website (with showinfo=0 parameter):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qTLOQCSwMpM?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

showinfo=0 does successfully remove the top panel with share & watch later buttons **in most browsers, but not everywhere**.

I noticed that on Chrome 62.0.3202.94 on Windows 10 it's still showing that panel:
[image]

How do I get rid of it on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It will now work at all any more

`showinfo` has been deprecated since 25/09/2018.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo